# Why doesnt this eventhandler cause a StackOverflow exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with 5 GridView controls all linked to the same SelectedIndexChanged event as follows

```
    <div id="containerOne" class ="containerLeft">
        <h2 class="WorkInProgressHeading">To Analyse</h2>
        <asp:LinkedGridView runat="server"  ID ="grdAwaitingAnalysis" CssClass="Grid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAltItem"/>
            <RowStyle CssClass="GridItem"/>
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridSelectedItem"/>
        </asp:LinkedGridView>
    </div>
    <div id="containerTwo" class="containerLeft">
        <h2 class="WorkInProgressHeading">Analysing...</h2>
        <asp:LinkedGridView runat="server" ID="grdAnalysisInProgress" CssClass="Grid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAltItem"/>
            <RowStyle CssClass="GridItem"/>
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridSelectedItem"/>
        </asp:LinkedGridView>
    </div> etc.....
```

In the code behind, the event handler is as follows

```
    protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sendingGrid = sender as LinkedGridView;

        if (sendingGrid.ID != "grdAwaitingAnalysis") grdAwaitingAnalysis.SelectedIndex = -1;
        if (sendingGrid.ID != "grdAnalysisInProgress") grdAnalysisInProgress.SelectedIndex = -1;
        if (sendingGrid.ID != "grdAwaitingReporting") grdAwaitingReporting.SelectedIndex = -1;
        if (sendingGrid.ID != "grdAwaitingInterp") grdAwaitingInterp.SelectedIndex = -1;
        if (sendingGrid.ID != "grdInterpInProgress") grdInterpInProgress.SelectedIndex = -1;

   }
```

I was surprised that this didnt cause a stackoverflow exception because when each selected index is set to -1 i expected the grid_SelectedIndexChanged event to fire again but it didn't.

Is this because it's a web page instead of a WPF / Winforms situation ?
I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, so am I wrong in thinking about as similar to a WPF / WinForms app ?

Thanks.

Comment: Will the real Jon Skeet please stand up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this because it's a web page instead of a WPF

Probably.  In a non-AJAX form, the `IndexChanged` event is only fired  *on postback*, if the index is different from the previous *rendering*.

In a WPF/Winforms world, the event is attached to the actual control, so when the value is changed the event fires *immediately*.

Keep in mind that the event only fires when the index *actually changes*.  Setting it to the same value will not fire the event.